# Java SortMap Comparator to have digit keys ordered after letter keys

Tags: java, comparator, digits, letter, sortedmap

I need a SortedMap where the Charachter keys are sorted this way: ('A'..'Z'..'0'..'9'), so character first, then digits, all in ascending order.
This is what I have tried so far, however, the output shows it fails in returning the sorting I want, because the values of the digit keys are still before the values of letter keys.
What am I doing wrong? Is there an even better way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SortedMap<Character, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<Character>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Character o1, Character o2) {
            if (Character.isDigit(o1) && Character.isLetter(o2)){
                return o2.compareTo(o1);
            }
            else if(Character.isLetter(o1) && Character.isDigit(o2)){
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
            else{
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        }
    });

    sortedMap.put('5', "five");
    sortedMap.put('8', "nine");
    sortedMap.put('A', "ALPHA");
    sortedMap.put('G', "GOLF");
    sortedMap.put('F', "FOXTROT");
    System.out.println(sortedMap.values());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the result "o1 > o2" if o1 is a digit and o2 is a letter, so return 1 in this case. Similarly, if o1 is a letter and o2 is a digit, you need to return the result "o1 < o2", i.e. return -1.

```
public int compare(Character o1, Character o2) {
   if (Character.isDigit(o1) && Character.isLetter(o2)){
      return 1;
   }
   else if(Character.isLetter(o1) && Character.isDigit(o2)){
      return -1;
   }
   else{
      return o1.compareTo(o2);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should always return -1 if `o1` is a letter and `o2` is a digit, because you *always* want the letter to go first.  And you should always return 1 if it's the opposite.

The only case where it should return `o1.compareTo(o2)` is in the final `else`, which means `o1` and `o2` are both either letters or numbers, and in that case, the comparator should simply follow natural order.

Answer (score 1):

Asusuming you're using Java 8+, declare your Map as:

```
SortedMap<Character, String> sortedMap = 
            new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(c -> (c + 197) % 255));
```

Optionally, you can extract "magic numbers" 197 and 255 into constants, or extract argument of `comparingInt(..)` into a constant.

Explanation:
chars 0..9 correspond to ASCII codes 48..57
ASCII codes for all the letters belong to range 65..122
Code above shifts codes a bit, moving numbers range to 245..254 and letters range to 7..64
Since Comparator compares shifted codes, it places letters before digits

Answer (score 0):

When you want all letters to come before all digits, and you get one digit and one letter, you should not be comparing them at all:

```java
public int compare(Character o1, Character o2) {
    if (Character.isDigit(o1) && Character.isLetter(o2)) {
        // o1 < o2 regardless of what values o1 and o2 are
        // So return any negative integer
        return -100;
    }
    else if (Character.isLetter(o1) && Character.isDigit(o2)) {
        // o1 > o2 regardless of what values o1 and o2 are
        // So return any positive integer
        return 100;
    }
    // Both must be letters or both must be integers
    // fall back to normal comparison, as you have already done
    return o1.compareTo(o2);
}
```

Comment: Yes it works, but it is a bad habit to get into.  Always return 1, -1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using a `ternary (?:)` construction outside the Map declaration to build the `Comparator`. I also added some extra values interspersed with yours to add variability.

```
        Comparator<Character> comp = (a, b) -> Character.isLetter(a)
                && Character.isDigit(b) ? -1 :
                Character.isLetter(b) && Character.isDigit(a) ? 1 :
                a.compareTo(b);

        SortedMap<Character, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(comp);
        sortedMap.put('Q', "Quebec");
        sortedMap.put('B', "Beta");
        sortedMap.put('5', "five");
        sortedMap.put('9', "nine");
        sortedMap.put('A', "ALPHA");
        sortedMap.put('3', "three");
        sortedMap.put('G', "GOLF");
        sortedMap.put('F', "FOXTROT");
        sortedMap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
A=ALPHA
B=BETA
F=FOXTROT
G=GOLF
Q=QUEBEC
3=three
5=five
9=nine
```